# PHP display business hours open or closed depending on time

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to get the minutes to work to echo "open" or "closed" depending on time. It works if i do not add the minutes, but not when adding minutes.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$hour = (int) date('H:i');

if ($hour >= 1215 && $hour <=1735) {
    // between 8:15am and 5:35pm
    echo "Open";
} else {
    echo "Closed";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a time, for example 18:55, your `date('H:i')` will output a string, `18:55` when using the format `H:i`. If you try to cast this to an integer, like you are with `(int)`, it will evaluate just the first number, `18`.

Simply remove the colon in your `date()` function! This will return a string `1855` from the date, which can be cast to an integer of that value. Although, it's not strictly needed to cast it to an integer, as PHP will treat a string of numbers as an integer.

So basically you just need

```
$hour = date("Hi");

if ($hour >= 1215 && $hour <= 1735) {
    // between 12:15 and 17:35
}
```

Answer (score 0):

final code for future learners. thanks Qirel

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$hour = (int) date('Hi');

if ($hour >= 0815 && $hour <= 1735) {
    // between 8:15am and 5:35pm
    echo "Open";
} else {
    echo "Closed";
}
?>
```